# Gradle : failed to create directory

Tags: android, android-studio

[I am a newbie and getting some errors like 1] gradel:failed to create directory 2] Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Failed to execute aapt 3]  Error:Gradle:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details .  I have tried changing the build version but it didn't worked i even tried to change aapt and many things but nothing worked for me.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmATI.png)

Comment: What is your question? You may need to edit your question to make it easier to understand what you are asking.

Comment: i have edited my question sir i hope now you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Provide Your Gradle.Build Too so we can see what is wrong.

Now, Check if The `compileSdkVersion` is the Same as `buildToolsVersion`

If `buildToolsVersion` is "21.0.3" Your `compileSdkVersion` needs to be "21"

Check and see what's what